Reading Current Sensor Data using ADS7961 with XMC4700
I am trying to develop driver code for ADS7961 by TI with XMC4700 over SPI interface to get current sensor value, But facing difficulties. If anyone has sample program developed for same please let me know.
So far I have tried interfacing ADS7961 with arduino and tried reading channels, its working, But when I try to interface it with XMC4700 its not showing any output.

If it is work on Arduino, that means your code able to talk to the chip via SPI and whatever you wrote work. What is not working is probably has to be with the SPI configuration on XMC4700.

A copy and past program wont help.
You have to configure the clock, the ports, the USIC peripheral and maybe also DMA,Interrupts or whatever you are using.
There are quite some possibilities to connect a SPI device.
The free Dave IDE offers a wide range of example programs.
The APP "SPI_MASTER" is good starting point. You get all configurations you need.
But here some questions to get closer to the problem:

Is the wiring correct?
Do you have an oscilloscope to compare the two devices?
Is the Chip-Select working correct?
Are the clock setting correct? There are quit some options:
Options in Dave

